# Preview is stretched on CameraX PreviewView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax, camera-api

i am exciting to use CameraX on my app.,
my reference from google officialy CameraX on github,
but something wrong., please help me.,

this my code to set aspect ratio

```
private fun aspectRatio(width: Int, height: Int): Int {
    val previewRatio = max(width, height).toDouble() / min(width, height)
    if (abs(previewRatio - RATIO_4_3_VALUE) <= abs(previewRatio - RATIO_16_9_VALUE)) {
        return AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
    }
    return AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
}
```

And this my preview code

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
    viewFinder=binding.surfaceView
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
        Log.d(TAG, "Screen metrics: ${metrics.widthPixels} x ${metrics.heightPixels}")
        val screenAspectRatio = aspectRatio(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        Log.d(TAG, "Preview aspect ratio: $screenAspectRatio")
        Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

        val rotation = viewFinder.display.rotation

        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .build()

        imageCapture = if (flashStatus) {
            ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                .setTargetRotation(rotationimage)
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .build()
        } else {
            ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                .setTargetRotation(rotationimage)
                .build()
        }

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        // Unbind use cases before rebinding
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        viewFinder.scaleType=PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER

        try {
            // Bind use cases to camera
            val cam = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)
            if (!flashStatus) {
                if (cam.cameraInfo.hasFlashUnit()) {
                    cam.cameraControl.enableTorch(true)
                }
            } else {
                cam.cameraControl.enableTorch(false)
            }
            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)


        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
```

and this output preview
[output preview is stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPbR5.png)

what is wrong on my code?

thank you for your help me folks.,

**UPDATE**
when my device on dark mode, the preview is normal.
[preview normal on dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxBad.jpg)
how to fixed in normal mode??

Comment: Which version of CameraX view artifact are you using? Is the issue reproducible on a different device? If you could provide a minimal code sample on GitHub that would be great.

Comment: CameraX version i am use 1.0.0 RC3 .,,

Comment: What is the device model you are using?

Comment: my device Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro MIUI 12, Android 10 .,

Comment: **LAST UPDATE**
the problem solved, PreviewView is work., 
i am changed the AppTheme from 

> "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Bridge"

 to 

> "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"